# xbindkeys works only on verbose mode, ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, xbindkeys

My xbindkeys works only on -verbose mode, without this mode, it doesn't react to my hotkeys.

```
xbindkeys -v
displayName = :0
rc file = /home/yerlan/.xbindkeysrc
rc guile file = /home/yerlan/.xbindkeysrc.scm
getting rc guile file /home/yerlan/.xbindkeysrc.scm.
WARNING : /home/yerlan/.xbindkeysrc.scm not found or reading not allowed.
1 keys in /home/yerlan/.xbindkeysrc

min_keycode=8     max_keycode=255 (ie: know keycodes)
"firefox"
    m:0x4 + c:24
    Control + q
starting loop...
```

What could cause the problem ?

```
cat ~/.xbindkeysrc 
# For the benefit of emacs users: -*- shell-script -*-
###########################
# xbindkeys configuration #
###########################
#
# Version: 1.8.6
#

"firefox" 
m:0x14 + c:24
control+q
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just needed to run `xbinkeys -p` after downloading and after every update